# Keep my repeating elements

Tags: python, list

I give Python a list, it returns it to me.

```
def Function(a={}):
    return a
```

When I repeat elements in a (a= 1, 1, 2) it will return me {1,2}. How could I make it keep my repeating elements?

Comment: `{}` is an empty dict not a list. Are you giving it a list or a dictionary?

Comment: {1, 2} is a set which is why there is no duplicate.  An empty list is [].

Comment: So I just had to change the paranthesis. Something tells me I should have figured it out on my own. Thank you!

Comment: Use list: `def Function(a={}): return list(a)`

Comment: That said, having a [mutable default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) is usually a tad risky.

Answer (score -1):

what you are doing is a dictionary, a dictionaries don't have duplicated elements. If the parameter is integer or a list it doesn't matter. when you declare the function as parameter you just put the name.

```
def func(l):

    return l
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little confused - I did the following and it worked:

```
def func(a={}):                                               
    return a

print(func((1, 1, 2)))
```

Comment: `type((1, 1, 2)) <class 'tuple'>`